# Update a props on a component rendered with the help of useTracker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-hooks

I want to update the props of several component rendered by a tracker (by using useTracker), to update the front without refreshing the page.

Here's a simple example of my problem :

My collection is ValuesCollection with 1 attribute by default (myValue) :
{ "myValue" : "defaultValue", "key" : "uniqKey"}

In the backend, a batch change this value to another value (take 10 sec per batch)

```
import { useTracker } from "meteor/react-meteor-data";
import { ValuesCollection } from "api/MongoAPI";

export default function MyPage() {
  const { values } = useTracker(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe("values", {});
    const values = ValuesCollection.find({}).fetch();
    return { values };
  });

  return (
    <Stack spacing={2}>
      {values.map((elem) => (
        <ValueComponent key={elem.key} myProps={elem.myValue}/>
      ))}
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

When i load the page with 5 object in ValuesCollection, i have

```
<Stack spacing={2}>
  <ValueComponent key=1 myProps="defaultValue"/>
  <ValueComponent key=2 myProps="defaultValue"/>
  <ValueComponent key=3 myProps="defaultValue"/>
  <ValueComponent key=4 myProps="defaultValue"/>
  <ValueComponent key=5 myProps="defaultValue"/>
</Stack>
```

After 10 seconds, my first object is updated in database, with **myValue="first"**.
My tracker **values** is updated, but my ValueComponent doesn't re render.
So, nothing happen on my front page.

```
<Stack spacing={2}>
  {/* Here, i want
  <ValueComponent key=1 myProps="first"/>
  */}
  <ValueComponent key=1 myProps="defaultValue"/>
  <ValueComponent key=2 myProps="defaultValue"/>
  <ValueComponent key=3 myProps="defaultValue"/>
  <ValueComponent key=4 myProps="defaultValue"/>
  <ValueComponent key=5 myProps="defaultValue"/>
</Stack>
```

How can I do to update my component as the collection updates to display the results in live ?

Comment: key is a reserved prop for react. And each key must be unique

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, bad example, key is not important here, i update my code

Comment: (key is important so be sure to have it). Have you logged the var values (the one outside the useTracker callback) ?

Comment: (i have it in my code) Yes, i have log it with : useEffect(() => { console.log(values) }, [values]). He updates each times a result came in the DB, so after 10 seconds, i have : [{ "myValue" : "first" }, {"myValue" : "defaultValue"}, {"myValue" : "defaultValue"}, {"myValue" : "defaultValue"}, {"myValue" : "defaultValue"}]

Comment: Kind of strange then because if the useEffect runs it means that the component is re-rendered as expected. Maybe an issue in Stack or ValueComponent components

Answer (score 1):

In order to refresh a React component you need to update the local state or the props. None of this is happening in your component. This is why in React you have mainly two options (and a third which I use in all my projects)

1. React context - pass props down to components
2. React containers - wrap a component into a data container
3. Redux - global store
4. Other global store solutions.

For a simple case like yours, separating data from the view would be the easiest thing to do and solution 2 is the easiest to implement.
If you need to do this in a large project, 1 or 3 would be your best options.

Ok there could be another way. In your tracker function include a state update. You don't need to use it further, just to update it.

e.g.

```js
const [lastUpdate, setLastUpdate] = React.useState(null)

//....
useTracker(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe("values", {});
    const values = ValuesCollection.find({}).fetch();
    return { values };
    setLastUpdate(Date.new())
  })
```

Comment: It's not possible to change the state in a tracker. React throws "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Comment: That totally makes sense :) because once you change the state ... your tracker runs again which leads to changing the state. In this case you need to move your tracker result to a prop outside the component.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong because (besides the bug mentioned in the other comments) the whole point of `useTracker` (and its' ancestor `withTracker`) is to be responsive. `values` is changing and therefore the component is being re-rendered. I don't think there is need for extra magic here. The question scenario is exactly what React and useTracker are for

Comment: @LaloMores I think you might mean "reactive" and not "responsive". ```values``` is not state nor prop. Why do you thing the component should re-render?! You base your statement on what exactly? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/re-rendering-components-in-reactjs/

Comment: Hi Paul. Yes, you're right. I meant "reactive". Sorry for the confusion there.
I base my statement on experience: I've used `useTracker` this way many times.
I guess `values` *is* state the same way usually things become state when using a **useX** hook.
Just found [this](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/tree/master/packages/react-meteor-data#usetrackerreactivefn-basic-hook) for a more official explanation:
"_useTracker manages its own state, and causes re-renders when necessary. There is no need to call React state setters from inside your reactiveFn_"

Comment: @LaloMores I think you are right. I am looking in the hook's code now and I thin what makes it update the component is the use of ```useReducer``` within the hook ```const useForceUpdate = () => useReducer(fur, 0)[1];```.  Ok that falls into the point 1, of my initial post and I must say that I had no clue the hook was using the reducer by default/design. Coming back to the initial problem, I now wonder whether it has been solved?!

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `useTracker` seems fine. And if you have tested that `values` actually changes, then it also works fine (as Hugo Mallet suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098468/update-a-props-on-a-component-rendered-with-the-help-of-usetracker/75222586#comment132528909_75098468)).
I think two suspects are in place:

1. You are not using the `MyProp` prop inside your `ValueComponent`
2. As your collection doesn't seem to have a `key` prop, it is possible you're assigning "undefined" as the key for all the items. Weird stuff happens when you mess with the keys. Do you get a warning in the console saying you have duplicate keys in your example? In such case you could could change the `key={elem.key}` with `key={elem._id}` to fix it up.

A debugging suggestion that would address both: log both `key` and `MyProp` inside your `ValueComponent` and see what you get.

Also, sharing the code of your ValueComponent would help.